# How to resize the bone to fit the object size?

Tags: rigging

The bone is too big compared to the arm size of my character. Does anyone know how to resize the bone?
[image: bone size]

Comment: Select Armature go to Properties Editor and under Object Data Properties > Viewport Display > Display as Stick (now it is Octahedral)

Comment: how to go to properties editor?

Comment: Google is your friend https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/editors/properties_editor.html

Comment: I found it! Thank you!!!